# Creating RadioButtons

Tags: java, swing

i was trying to create two radiobuttons in the frame using swing concept .. here is my code

```
import javax.swing.*;

class abc
{
      abc()
      {
        JFrame j=new JFrame();
        JRadioButton jb1=new JRadioButton("a)first");
        JRadioButton jb2=new JRadioButton("b)Second");
        jb1.setBounds(50,100,70,30);
        jb1.setBounds(50,150,70,30);
        ButtonGroup b=new ButtonGroup();
        b.add(jb1);
        b.add(jb2);
        j.add(jb1);
        j.add(jb2);
        j.setSize(500, 500);
        j.setLayout(null);
        j.setVisible(true);
      }
}
public class Swingss
{
   public static void main(String[] args) 
   {
      new abc();
   }
}
```

but i got only one radio button inside the frame ... may i know where i did the mistake

Comment: Don't use fix sizes for your buttons. Use [LayoutManager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) instead.

Answer (score 1):

You mistyped `jb1` twice instead of `jb2`:

```
jb1.setBounds(50,100,70,30);
jb1.setBounds(50,150,70,30); // -> jb2
```